# Condition for Vue.js not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement

Im working on an vue app where im getting some errors due to script executing on some sites. If i add the following code, my problem gets fixed:

```
    if (
  window.location.href ===
  'chrome-extension://fbdhgoijldjhaidjclojhnbibaipkfmn/index.html#/'
) {
  console.log('dont run')
} else {
  new Vue({
    el: '#context-menu-app-1',
    // components: { App },
    render: (h) => h(App)
  })
}
```

However the value "chrome-extension://fbdhgoijldjhaidjclojhnbibaipkfmn/index.html#/" will vary depending on user, so i cant use this as a permanent fix. Instead im trying to match my condition to search if the href value starts with 'chrome-extention' , like so:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('chrome-extension://')) {
  console.log('dont run')
} else {
  new Vue({
    el: '#context-menu-app-1',
    // components: { App },
    render: (h) => h(App)
  })
}
```

But its not working, with the indexOf method, my error comes back. Any advise how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong here. `indexof` will return the position of the first occurrence.

> [The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

In your case the return value will be `0` which evaluates to false.

What you must do is check if the return value is not `-1`.

> [This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Try the following code;

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('chrome-extension://') !== -1) {
  console.log('dont run')
} else {
  new Vue({
    el: '#context-menu-app-1',
    // components: { App },
    render: (h) => h(App)
  })
}
```